# Bouncing ball deflates when hitting surface

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

Plane has a collision. The ball has a soft body. Bending of 5. turned goal off. I baked and when I animated I get the image attached, How do I keep the shape of the ball normal with a minor bending bounce? I get the same outcome when I bending to 0

[image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the *Pull* and *Push*. Try settings like `Pull: 0.950` and `Push: 0.999`, this will result in bounces while keeping the shape of the ball.